# How to expand a variable to a key with a slash/special character and use it as an argument in jq

Tags: jq

With `jq` I'm trying to delete a node of which its path is a variable that expands to a string with a slash (special character).

So, this works (a path with a special character needs to be quoted):

```
cat package-lock.json | jq 'del(.packages."foo/bar")' > package-lock-new.json
```

And this works (adding an argument from the environment variables):

```
export ROOT=packages
cat package-lock.json | jq --arg ROOT "$ROOT" 'del(.$ROOT."foo/bar")' > package-lock-new.json
```

However, combined - expanding the environment variable in a quoted path - does not work:

```
export BAR=bar
cat package-lock.json | jq --arg BAR "$BAR" 'del(.packages."foo/$BAR".version)' > package-lock-new.json
```

What would be the right escaping for `jq`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to concatenate the literal part with the variable, and make it a key identifier:

```bash
# using string interpolation
jq --arg BAR "$BAR" 'del(.packages."foo/\($BAR)".version)'

# using string addition
jq --arg BAR "$BAR" 'del(.packages["foo/" + $BAR].version)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77129388/84940) is more robust, but if you already exported the environment variable `$BAR`, you could just rely on bash to do the substitution:

```
§ echo '{ "packages" : { "foo/bar" : { "name": "P1", "version" : 1 } } }' | 
  jq 'del(.packages."foo/'$BAR'".version)'
```

```
{
  "packages": {
    "foo/bar": {
      "name": "P1"
    }
  }
}
```

If you did not export the variable, you could supply it inline too:

```
§ echo '{ "packages" : { "foo/bar" : { "name": "P1", "version" : 1 } } }' | 
  BAR=bar jq 'del(.packages."foo/'$BAR'".version)'
```